# I fail to use C++ pointer to point to the std::vector that is returned by a class method

Tags: c++

I tried to access the private vector member. I am curious why it did not work when I make the pointer point to the return vector (last case)

```
  std::vector<double>* ptr3 = &(obj.GetVector());
  std::cout << ptr3->at(0) << '\n'; //does not work
```

However, when I point to the newly created vector, it worked.

```
  std::vector<double> vec3(obj.GetVector());
  std::cout << vec3[3] << '\n'; //work. get 1.4

  std::vector<double>* ptr1 = &vec3;
  std::cout << ptr1->at(0) << '\n'; //work. get 1.1
```

The difference is just about skipping one line (assigned it to a vector first)

When the method directly return the pointer and I assigned it to another pointer, it also worked.

```
  std::vector<double>* ptr2 = obj.GetVector2();
  std::cout << ptr2->at(1) << '\n'; //work. get 1.2
```

Could you please teach/explain me on this behavior? Thank you.

The code of the cases discussed above is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class AClass {
 public:
  AClass(): vec1({1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4}) {}
  std::vector<double> GetVector() {
    return vec1;
  }
  std::vector<double>* GetVector2() {
    return &vec1;
  }
 private:
  std::vector<double> vec1;
};

int main() {
  AClass obj;
  std::vector<double> vec2;
  vec2 = obj.GetVector();
  std::cout << vec2[2] << '\n'; //work. get 1.3

  std::vector<double> vec3(obj.GetVector());
  std::cout << vec3[3] << '\n'; //work. get 1.4

  std::vector<double>* ptr1 = &vec3;
  std::cout << ptr1->at(0) << '\n'; //work. get 1.1

  std::vector<double>* ptr2 = obj.GetVector2();
  std::cout << ptr2->at(1) << '\n'; //work. get 1.2

  std::vector<double>* ptr3 = &(obj.GetVector());
  std::cout << ptr3->at(0) << '\n'; //does not work
    //get
    //"Unhandled exception at 0x760FC54F in access_vector.exe"
    //"exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0033FA90

  std::system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `AClass::GetVector()` returns a copy of the vector `vec1`, not the actual vector `vec1` declared in your `AClass` class.

So this line:

`std::vector<double>* ptr3 = &(obj.GetVector());`

assigns the address of a temporary copy, which leads to undefined behavior if you use `ptr3` after that line, since the copy is now gone.

---

One solution is to return a reference to the vector, and not a copy:

```
std::vector<double>& GetVector() {
    return vec1;
  }
```

The gist of this is that if you want to work with the original vector, return a reference to that vector, not a copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<double> GetVector() {
  return vec1;
}
```

What's actually happening in the snippet above is that you are returning a **copy** of the vector.

Then you try to do this:

```
std::vector<double>* ptr3 = &(obj.GetVector());
```

Let's try to see what is happening here.

First, you get a copy of the vector:

```
obj.GetVector()
```

then, you get the address **of the copy**:

```
&(obj.GetVector())
```

This address is then assigned to `ptr3`. The expression then ends, and the copy was never stored anywhere (remember, you just stored its address, instead of the object itself). Since it is a temporary, it is destroyed at the end of the expression.

Finally, you try to use the address you just got:

```
ptr3->at(0)
```

But since the object is destroyed, the address now points to garbage. This is why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

`AClass::GetVector()` returns a copy of the vector, so `std::vector<double>* ptr3 = &(obj.GetVector());` calls that function, which creates a copy as a temporary, then takes the address of that temporary and stores it in `ptr3`, after which the temporary is destroyed. So you have a dangling pointer - a pointer to an object that no longer exists.

Returning the pointer directly works because the pointer is directly to the data member, which still exists; and storing the copied vector into a local and then getting a pointer to it also works because, again, you're getting a pointer to an object with a lifetime at least as long as the pointer.